# How to make inqurerjs work with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, inquirer, inquirerjs

I've got a function which uses inquirer to ask a series of questions and then calls a function in the `inquirer.prompt(q).then()` function with the answers. This works perfectly well but I'm trying to do some refactoring of my app and I want to be able to make my function return the set of answers to be called elsewhere. However, the code I have seems to return nothing at all. I thought I'd followed the examples correctly but apparently not. Can someone shed some light on the issue, please?

Here is the function:

```
const inquirer = require('inquirer')
const questions = require('../data/questions')

// Ask the user the predefined questions
module.exports = questionTime = async () => await inquirer.prompt(questions)
```

I've also tried to write it out the long-form way to see if that helped but to no avail:

```
module.exports = questionTime = async function () {
  const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions)
  return answers
}
```

If I `console.log` `answers` instead of returning then I can see the output but if I import the function to another file and `console.log` that I get nothing:

e.g. `console.log(questionTime())`

Comment: where is `questions` defined?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the full file.

Comment: OK, so `questionTime()` will return a promise. You will have to await it to get the answers. There is no magical way to be able to access answers *now*, when they are only available in the *future*. Wrapping things in yet another `async` function is not going to change this.